# Core dump when using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am writing a simple code using structures in C++, but on compilation with g++, I am getting core dumped error. If I am using cin to input "Mario" in player.name below, no error is reported. Can anyone please explain what is going wrong?

```
struct character
{
    char *name;
};

int main()
{
    character player;
    player.name = new char[10];
    player.name = "Mario";
    cout<<player.name<<endl;
    delete player.name;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't see where do you use the std::cin function in the code above :/

Comment: You're deleting a string literal -- bad times! Try `strcpy` or `std::string`.

Comment: This: `player.name = "Mario";` is not working for C++. Forget this if you're working with `char*`.

Comment: @Forgottn Actually, it does (at least in C++03).

Comment: When you allocate memory with `new[]`, you must deallocate it with `delete[]`.

Comment: Not really. You can do this: `char myString[] = "Mario";` and this `char *pString = myString;`. But it's not allowed to declare a *pointer* with const string expression type. If it works, say on Visual C++, it's not guaranteed, that it'll work on other compilers.

Comment: @Forgottn: What the hell are you talking about? `T x[]` decays to `T*` for any `T` and any expression. It's absolutely legal and Standard to define `const char* x = "str";` and in C++03, `char* x = "str"` as they have a special rule allowing them to violate `const`.

Comment: @DeadMG, T x[] is downcasted to T*. Try to upcast T* to T[].

Comment: @Forgottn You’re still wrong. The *string literal* decays to a pointer. `char* foo = "Hello";` is valid in C++03. `char const* foo = "Hello";` is valid in C++11 still.

Answer (score 8):

Replace `char*` with `std::string` and drop the lines with `new` and `delete`, and you will no longer have a problem.

This code fails because, primarily, when you assign to the pointer it does not copy the contents into the thing pointed at- it just changes the thing the pointer points to.

In general, *always* use classes to own resources- in this case, a string. Happily, the Standard provides such a class for you.

Comment: Hmm. On the one hand, yes, this answer helps. But on the other it would be beneficial to give *some* pointers (no pun intended) in the direction of an explanation. Or not. The OP probably isn’t at a level where understanding about pointers is crucial.

Comment: @Konrad: You mean "Remove all lines inside `main()` except `return 0;`, and you will no longer have a problem." isn't helpful?

Comment: @Ben That’s not what DeadMG wrote, and I actually have to take my comment back mostly.

Comment: @Konrad: Perhaps, but it illustrates that the goal is understanding, not "you no longer have a problem".

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, I completely agree. My answer helps him understand how to write code that achieves the same goal with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
player.name = new char[10];
player.name = "Mario";
```

You just overwrote the pointer, which leaked the buffer of 10 characters.  You probably meant

```
player.name = new char[10];
strcpy(player.name, "Mario");
```

But using `std::string` is a much better fix, see [DeadMG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938459/103167) for that.

[As Ed points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10938501/103167), you also deleted the buffer wrong, you need `delete []`.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on using new etc instead of string, change

```
player.name = "Mario";
```

to

```
strcpy(player.name, "Mario");
```

Also change

```
delete player.name;
```

to

```
delete[] player.name;
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the two lines

```
player.name = new char[10];
player.name = "Mario";
```

You allocate an array to player.name but then immediately reset the pointer to a static buffer. When you call delete, you are trying to delete a static array of characters, which will be a segfault.

You need to COPY the data into the newly allocated memory, not reset the pointer:

```
player.name = new char[10];
strcpy(player.name,"Mario");
delete[] player.name;
```

(Note that freeing a pointer to an array of objects, you should use `delete[]` and not just `delete`. In this trivial example, there is no difference, but if the array was an object with a destructor, the destructor will not be called if you only use `delete`.